# Tensorflow slicing

Tags: python, indexing, tensorflow

I try slicing a tensor using the [tf.Tensor.**getitem**](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#__getitem__) function as below:

```
indices = [0, 5]
data[:,:,indices]
```

But I get the following error:

> TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Comment: Solution may be in __getitem__ doc: "The notation is similar to NumPy with the restriction that currently only support basic indexing"

Comment: But I could I slice to get only these indices?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
data[:, :, 0:6]
```